# Add a div element on Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I need to add my favorite text to middle-top of my `map` div, so I have:

```
<div id="map" style="height:300px;">
   <div style="width:150px;background-color:red; z-index:1000;"> Hello World !!</div>
</div>
```

And this is my simplified JS code:

```
<script>               
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Lat = 32.646540;
        var Lon = 51.667743;
        map = L.map('map').setView([Lat, Lon], 19);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: 'Thanks to OSM',
            maxZoom: 19
        }).addTo(map);               
    });
</script>
```

And the problem is that the `Red Text` goes behind the map and I can't manage it.
Before loading the map :
[image]

After loading the map :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add your Hello World `div` a higher `z-index` like `z-index: 9999`

**Update**

Now I see it. You add the hello World div as child to the map. You have to add it as sibling.

```
<div class="box"> Hello World</div>
<div id="map" style="height:300px;"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px; /* half of the width */
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried `z-index:99999999` but not worked.

Comment: I need the `Hello World` to be on the map not outside the map.Using sibling makes a `Hello World` out of the map region and not on the map region.

Comment: No. If you use the css porporty `position: absolute` you can set the div at any position of the screen: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/3k2ovqsh/